# No overload Method takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, date, tostring

I want to convert the format of datetime into date. So i tried the following convertion. But it is always showing line error like `No overload Method takes 2 arguments`.
Input:

```
private const string Needdate = "date";
private const string Needbydate = "dd-mmm-yyyy";
```

The following code is the main convertion of the date. But the line is showing an error.

```
jsonNeedby.NeedDate = Needdate.ToString(Needbydate,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I could not find the issue.

Comment: `Needdate`  is a string and not a `DateTime` object. What are you trying to do here ?

Comment: some time needdate is returning time also. So i want to convert that into date.

Comment: Is there a fixed format ? Like day/Month(as number)/ Year ?

Comment: Can you provide two sample dates ? One with time and one without time ?

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong and from your comments, you need `DateTime.ParseExact`. Just like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Needbydate, Needbydate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

But you need to be 100 % sure that `Needbydate` is the format, or you'll get an exception.

Also, the `mmm` part in `"dd-mmm-yyyy";` is not the month, you need to use `"dd-MM-yyyy";` or `"dd-MMM-yyyy";`

> mmm is for seconds. also m and mm
>
> **M** for a single digit month (4)
>
> **MM** for two digits month (04)
>
> **MMM** for Abbreviated month name (Dec)
>
> **MMMM** for full month name (Decemeber)

Answer (score 0):

Consider below code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Needdate, Needbydate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I hope this will work in your case.